# Rails : How to create an object of class within a controller which is in another namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I'm using **CarrierWave** to upload files from the **AngularJS** client. The **uploader** generated for the **carrierWave** is in **another namespace** while the **controller** is in **another namespace.**

So when I'm trying to **create** an **object** of **uploader** inside the **controller**, I am getting the following **error** :

```
uninitialized constant Api::V1::ProductsController::FileUploader
```

Here is my directory structure :

```
app
|--controllers
   |--api
      |--controllers
         |--api
            |--v1
               |--products_controller.rb
|--uploaders
   |--file_uploader.rb
```

**The Products Controller**

```
  class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

  ......

  def createFromExcel
    puts "------------------------------------"
    puts params[:file]
    puts "------------------------------------"
    uploader = FileUploader.new
    uploader.store!(params[:file])
  end


end
```

**The FileUploader class :**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_whitelist
     %w(xlsx xls)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

How can I create an object of **FileUploader class** within my **Controller**?

Comment: Why do you need to create it within your controller? Carrierreave works on your model; did you set up a model with `mount_uploader`?

Comment: I do not want a permanent storage, I just need to iterate over the spreadsheet and read the data and save it into the db.

Comment: Try adding `require 'uploaders/file_uploader'` to the controller

Answer (score 0):

try using `uploader = ::FileUploader.new`

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a constant from `main` (the "global namespace") instead of the current module nesting (the "namespace") use `::`

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  # use snake_case not camelCase
  def create_from_excel
    uploader = ::FileUploader.new
    uploader.store!(params[:file])
  end
end
```

See:

- [Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)
- [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)